# What are common mistakes to avoid before submitting Apple Watch applications?

Tags: app-store, watchkit, apple-watch, submission

The Apple Watch application review process seems to be [getting a lot of hate](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1120811#1120811) recently.

I personally think we should credit Apple for dealing with a new language *and* a new device, but there is no excuse for not maintaining a proper list of known issues regarding Apple Watch application development.

There have been some [weird solutions](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1120211#1120211) to some equally [weird issues](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1119279#1119279). I figured it was time to ask this question already.

More importantly (or less for some weird people) the Apple Developer Forums looks nowhere as great as StackOverflow.

So pick a common mistake, any common mistake.

---

Although an answer has been accepted, I strongly encourage WatchKit developers to share their own experiences. There's always something waiting to be screwed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've rounded up some common issues here that you may find helpful: http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/2015/4/2/submitting-your-watchkit-app

Comment: Priceless!!! You should add separating the asset catalog of the iPhone icons and the Watch (it is super common issue).

Comment: I think that's in there somewhere, but I'll definitely add it if not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Opening an Apple Watch application project using Xcode 6.3

This might accidentally set your deployment version to iOS 8.3, which you should immediately rectify, followed by bleaching your eyes and drinking Kleenex.

Comment: How do you fix this?

Comment: By changing the deployment version.